# Is this design to control a BLDC with 1 PWM signal feasible?

Tags: dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I've started designing my own BLDC speed controller for a RC Car. I've been reading [this document](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/AN3998-Sensorless-BLDC-MC-AVR-MCU-Fam-DS00003998.pdf) from Microchip where they use 6 seperate PWM signals from the MCU to drive the MOSFETs which, to me, sounds like a pain to do especially because the MCU doesn't have that many timers which can be routed to pins so they have to use the CCL, blah, blah, blah. My thought is to configure just 1 PWM signal then route that through buffers which can be toggled with the IO to turn on/off the desired phases.

I've attached a rough schematic to illustrate what I am describing. This design seems feasible to me but I'm wondering if I am overlooking anything.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Is it feasible, yes. But I don't understand why you wouldn't use directly 6 PWM. It would be so much simpler to control. A good thing is with that topology, if you want, you can do both (each enables are PWM and PWM stays 1).

Each PWM doesn't requires it's own timer. Every one requires a Copy Compare PWM module. These are what actually generate a PWM. The timer set your frequency and the CCP the width of your pulse.